# What is the right way to receive notifications or updates (e.g. webhooks) from Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, onchange, webhooks, spreadsheet

Here is my task:
Each time something happens in a Google Spreadsheet (e.g. a new row created\updated\deleted etc) i need to know what exactly happened in the spreadsheet. Currently Google sends HTTP POST request to my address with very little information is there a way to see what exactly changed (data) ?

I subscribed Google notifications (webhooks) to my URL-address. By using REST method https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/watch.
There are some headers in the incoming data on every change.

```php
Headers: [
    [content-length] => [
        [0] => 0
    ]
    [accept-encoding] => [
        [0] => gzip,deflate,br
    ]
    [user-agent] => [
        [0] => APIs-Google; (+https://developers.google.com/webmasters/APIs-Google.html)
    ]
    [connection] => [
        [0] => keep-alive
    ]
    [x-goog-resource-uri] => [
        [0] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/13wNPQC70ykcvUohPYA_ZEEy4RBGrJQLl3_wl5PitDJA?acknowledgeAbuse=false&fields=*&supportsAllDrives=false&supportsTeamDrives=false&alt=json
    ]
    [x-goog-resource-id] => [
        [0] => UALs5Bv0Ku6_CV0MOSIukJZPmuw
    ]
    [x-goog-message-number] => [
        [0] => 19961
    ]
    [x-goog-changed] => [
        [0] => properties]
    ]
    [x-goog-resource-state] => [
        [0] => update
    ]
    [x-goog-channel-expiration] => [
        [0] => Thu, 07 Nov 2019 09:56:42 GMT
    ]
    [x-goog-channel-id] => [
        [0] => sheetsevents_123
    ]
    [accept] => [
        [0] => '*/*'
    ]
    [host] => [Array
        [0] => {MY_HOST}
    ]
    [content-type] => [
        [0] => 
    ]
]
```

I need to get full info about changed entity (row, cells, data)

Comment: It depends if the changes on the spreadsheet are manually made by a user or automatically by a script. Also, I think you forgot to attach the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah. I attached a code with headers

Comment: Oh ok I understand now. Is the spreadsheet edited manually?

Comment: I need to do this on the server side. Table can be modified by user or script. App Script is not my solution

Comment: The Sheets API doesn't return that much information, and with Drive you can only check if a Sheet was edited. In Apps Script would be possible for manually edited sheets, but not edited by a script.